# jQuery Accordion - Open first slice

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to display the first "slice" of this accordion on load. ie I would like the first slide to be open by default when the page loads.

I have tried to add 'display:block' to the ul, but no luck

```
/* Vertical Accordion Style */
.va-container{
    position:relative;
    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
        top: -47px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
}         
.va-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#000;
        left: 0px;
}
.va-slice{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.va-slice-1{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Airfreight22.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-2{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Seafreight2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-3{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Satellite.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-4{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/41.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-5{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/41.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-6{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/41.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-7{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/41.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-color-1{
    background-color:#97c5eb;
}
.va-slice-color-2{
    background-color:#68ace5;
}
.va-slice-color-3{
    background-color:#0072cf;
}
.va-slice-color-4{
    background-color:#0039a6;
}
.va-slice-color-5{
    background-color:#00338e;
}
.va-slice-color-6{
    background-color:#002c76;
}
.va-slice-color-7{
    background-color:#002144;
}
.va-title{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:40px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;
}
.va-content{
    display:none;
    margin-left:25px;


}
.va-slice p{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family:Georgia, serif;
}
.va-slice ul{
    margin-top:20px;
}
.va-slice ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 2px;
}
.va-slice ul li a{
    color:#000;
    background:#eede2f;
    padding:3px 6px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.va-slice ul li a:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:none;
}
.va-nav span{
    width:40px;
    height:25px;
    background:transparent url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
    position:absolute;
    top:-35px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-20px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    opacity:0.7;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    z-index:100;
}
.va-nav span.va-nav-next{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/next.png);
    top:auto;
    bottom:-35px;
}
.va-nav span:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}

/* End Additional CSS Styles */

<div class="container">

            <div id="va-accordion" class="va-container">
                <div class="va-nav">
                    <span class="va-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                    <span class="va-nav-next">Next</span>
                </div>
                <div class="va-wrapper">
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-1">
                        <div class="va-title">Airfreight</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Henry Watson</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-2">
                        <div class="va-title">Seafreight</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Keith Johnson</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-3">
                        <div class="va-title">Satellite Tracking</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Andrew Alaniz</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-4">
                        <div class="va-title">Guarding</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Ben Freeman</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-5">
                        <div class="va-title">Machine Moving</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Alex Schuman</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-6">
                        <div class="va-title">Investigations</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Maria Wales</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-7">
                        <div class="va-title">Transport</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Paul White</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/FSI5/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/FSI5/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/FSI5/jquery.vaccordion.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
                    visibleSlices   : 5,
                    expandedHeight  : 250,
                    animOpacity     : 0.1,
                    contentAnimSpeed: 100
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you using the jquery ui accordion widget? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @ckundo  No, I am using what I found here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/22/vertical-sliding-accordion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know this plugin, so i do not have documented solution.
What always work for me in similar situation is:

```
$(".va-slice-1").click()
```

Run it just after initialize accordion.

Comment: -thank you for your answer, it works great.  Can I trigger this for various slices on my navigation menu buttons? ie if I select the second nav menu button to open the second page, can I make it trigger the second slice on open?

Comment: IMO there is no problem. This call just tells jQuery to trigger the same job like after user click. For other slice use other selector name or just by table `$($("va-slice")[n]).click();` - where n is slice number.
Also native click call should work: `$("va-slice")[n].click()` - please note that this does not trigger click event by jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the JQuery UI accordion? If you are you can specify the paramater "active : true" where you instantiate your accordion, it's actually expanded by default in JQueryUI. If you are not using the jQuery UI accordion is there a reason why you can't?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  No, I am using what I found here tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/22/vertical-sliding-accordion    I am not very farmiliar with jquery, and chose this tutorial to start out

Comment: I would really recommend choosing jQueryUI's accordion. It has bundles of documentation, you'll find so many people will be able to help you out should you encounter issues and it'll save you so much stress in the future as you have a whole community contributing to its ongoing development.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `active` option when you are attaching the accordion behavior

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 1 });
```

[jQuery UI accordion docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

**EDIT**

The plugin you're using does not accept a default option, and it adds css height to the element inline via javascript. To open the slice by default, can fire a javascript click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.va-slice:first').trigger('click.vaccordion');
});
```

Alternatively, try adding the `data-expanded` attribute and default styles on the element inline.

```
<div data-expanded="true" class="va-slice va-slice-2" style="top: 0px; height: 350px; opacity: 1;">
```

Comment: The plugin code that documents the event handler and data attribute is [here](https://gist.github.com/ckundo/5380154#file-gistfile1-js-L371) and [here](https://gist.github.com/ckundo/5380154#file-gistfile1-js-L18)